# How to implement soft delete in SQL on data with foreign key relationships?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, sql-delete

I have a requirement to change the behavior of the "delete" function on a web application on a table that has 5 child foreign key relationships. It is a fairly large sized web application so I am looking for the least risky and lowest impact change so that it will require the minimum amount of changes to the web application.

I can think of two options:

1. add a column to the table `deleted`with default `0`, and `1` will indicate that the record has been deleted. This will require updating all selects on the table (and also, on it's child tables, as they are now orphaned) to include the clause `where deleted = 0`. The web app is old and not well written (repeated code) so there are many places that will require this change, so it is risky that one or more locations might be missed.
2. Move the record to another copy of the table, specifically for deleted records. I would likely need to mirror every child table as well.

Option 1 seems to be more effort up front, but more maintainable in the future, option 2 is not much work up front, minimal changes to web app, but very messy. Are there other options ?

Comment: If you are on Sql Server 2016, maybe row level security would work on Option 1 (filtering deleted=0) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/us-en/library/dn765131.aspx

Comment: What was the reason behind changing behaviour? If you are going to use these soft deleted records eg. for displaying historical data than option 1 is basically your only option. From architecture point of view I would also go with option 1 as synchonizing two database mirrors will be problematic especially if someone will make some structure changes to source - you will from that point need to keep track of changes on 2 databases which is not what I would recommend.

Answer (score 4):

This is an excellent example of why I am so fond of views.

- Create the new column, Deleted
- Rename the table: MyData => AllMyData
- Create a view with the old name that exposes the data from the table exactly the way it looked before, but only for the "undeleted" rows.

Example:

```
create view MyData as
    select ...
    from   AllMyData
    where  Deleted = 0
```

- Write triggers on the view to handle DML as if it was the original table.
- Create another view to expose the deleted rows.

Example:

```
create view DeletedMyData as
    select ...
    from   AllMyData
    where  Deleted = 1
```

- Implement a "soft delete" and "undelete" functionality within the app. This code will be the only code directly accessing the table, setting the value of Deleted to 0 or 1 as appropriate. *Existing code will need no modification.*
- The child tables will probably require no changes at all. Since they are likely queried by joining with the undeleted view (the one with the original table name), records referring to "deleted" data will not be exposed but will be automatically re-exposed when data is undeleted.
- UPDATE: The ON_DELETE trigger on the `MyData` view would just issue an update against the actual table, setting the Deleted value to 1. An UNDELETE action can be implemented using the ON_DELETE trigger on the `DeletedMyData` view to set the value to 0. So issuing a Delete on the `MyData` view would perform a soft delete (the record would vanish from the `MyData` data set and appear in `DeletedMyData`) and issuing a Delete on the `DeletedMyData` view would perform a soft undelete (the record would vanish from the `DeletedMyData` data set and reappear in `MyData`).